# How can I make smooth scrolling on my webpages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please note that I'm not looking for animated scrolling for when user is clicking a button but for when the user is scrolling with his mouse-wheel.

All JQuery plugins that I found are solving the click-and-scroll problem.

Is there a way for absolute smooth scrolling? JS? CSS? or am I only dreaming?

Comment: please share whatever you have done till now.

Comment: You need to listen to the `mousewheel` event.

Comment: Try parallax scrolling search for it

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/
OR http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/auto-load-records-on-page-scroll will solve the issue

Comment: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/ is another good option for you. See the demo : http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html

Comment: @LeoDeng - **NO**. you need to listen to `scroll` event, and when it ends, add some additional smooth scrolling

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and see of your URLs are relevant!